# Call C# function Blazor Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

Need some help sorting an error added a screenshot of code and the error returned by the code.
Trying to call a C# function from Jquery and pass parameters along.

_Host

```
        function getElementSVG(e) {
            var position = getPosition(e);
            var circle = makeSVG('circle', { cx: position.pointx, cy: position.pointy, r: 0.02, stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 0.5, fill: 'black' });
            document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id).appendChild(circle);
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('PeopleCounterWeb', 'AddPointToList', position.pointx, position.pointy).then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
            return position;
        }

        function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
            alert(data.d);

        }

        function fnerrorcallback(result) {
            alert(result.statusText);
        }
        function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
            var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
            for (var k in attrs)
                el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
            return el;
        }
        function getPosition(e) {
            var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
            var y = e.clientY - rect.top;

            var width = rect.width;
            var height = rect.height;
            var pointx = ((x / width) * 100).toFixed(2);
            var pointy = ((y / height) * 100).toFixed(2);
            return {
                pointx,
                pointy
            }
        };
```

MainMap.cshtml

```
    [JSInvokable]
    public string AddPointToList(string x, string y)
    {
        var alpha = x + "-" + y;
        return "";
        //Points.Add(obj[0], obj[1]);
    }
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qBY1.png)

[[Error]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STXFX.png)

Comment: Paste your code as text, not as images. The same thing with your error message. Images cannot be searched, copy/pasted from and don't get read by screen readers. Not to mention its a lot easier to paste text than it is to take a screenshot, find a place to upload an image and then link to said image.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke a message on an instance without passing a reference to that instance. Without an instance you can only call static methods.

You'll need to create an instance of DotNetReference in C# and pass it to JS.

There is a section on Blazor University about calling C# from JS - https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/